# CLOSED - How to invoke a javascript function after a View or PartialView is rendered?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller

I am using MVC to render a View.
The view has a single DIV element and a SCRIPT element.
The SCRIPT element has a simple alert('hello world').

When the view is rendered I expected to see the alert popup. Unfortunately this is NOT the case.

What can be done to invoke a script function after a View is rendered?

View.cshtml:

```
<div id="hello"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Hello World!');
    $('#hello').html('Hello world.');
</script>
```

*** Updated ***
My serious apologies. I found the issue. The problem was that within my script section I was setting an innerHTML without wrapping the string text with quotes. I guess this caused the browser to be confused and just silently crash. I found this out, by happenstance/luck, when I was looking at the debugging console (F12).

Comment: Are you missing single quote in alert func?

Comment: @KarthikMR, yup. good catch. it was just a typo. The actual code is syntactically correct (intellisense confirms it). :)

Comment: Is it partial view or view? And how is it called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place below line of code inside $(document).ready();

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
alert('Hello World!');
    $('#hello').html('Hello world.');
});
```

Comment: Isn't $(document).ready() invoked when the entire document is initially loaded? I am looking for when a View is rendered. Or is this still the same thing?  Worth a try... trying this now.

Comment: Hmm, This did not work. Note that this snippet is not in the main/index cshtml. It is in another view which is invoked when I navigate to that URL by setting window.location.href.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function()
{
  alert("Hello world!");
  $("#hello").html("Hello world.");
});
```